# Dynamic query with SELECT IN Node JS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I will explain my problem shortly.
I have to select price inside my database about more services.

I am passing an array of ID of services and I am using a SELECT query to get all information about it.

```
let serviceIDSplitted = ServicesID.split(','); // To split the service id

var tokens = new Array(serviceIDSplitted.length).fill('?').join(','); // To generate the ?

let appointmentGetPriceQuery = `SELECT ServicePrice, ServiceDuration FROM SalonService WHERE PlaceID = ? AND ServiceID IN (${tokens});`; // The query
```

The query is good because if I try to make a console.log() its printing well but when I try to execute it I got this problem:

```
"SELECT ServicePrice, ServiceDuration FROM SalonService WHERE PlaceID = 'x' AND ServiceID IN ('1', 'e12204d6abf65c509d310057681b6a1a',?);"
```

I tried to debug and the main problem is this:
I got 2 services + 1 PlaceID and it will put inside query 4 ? instead of 3
I got 3 services + 1 PlaceID and it will put inside query 5 ? instead of 4

Debugging the "tokens" variable the ? are ok, even inside the print of final query but when I try to execute it not.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you explain in more layman's terms as the above description is not that detailed? Can you explain in some simple terms, what is your expectation?

Comment: I need that the ? are correct but actually I got every time a wrong dynamic ? because I got one more respect to the right result

Comment: `var tokens = new Array(serviceIDSplitted.length. - 1).fill('?').join(',');` does this help? When you only need 3 elements, create only 3 why do you create 4?

Comment: I tried with -1 the problem is that when I got 3 ? the -1 is working well, when I got 1 ? and I do -1 it will go to 0 and it won't work. Its strange bug. I already tried with -1

Comment: Yes, I thought you have a minimum 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let serviceIDSplitted = ServicesID.split(','); // To split the service id
let len = serviceIDSplitted.length === 1 || serviceIDSplitted.length === 0 ? 1 : serviceIDSplitted.length -1;
var tokens = new Array(len).fill('?').join(','); // To generate the ?

let appointmentGetPriceQuery = `SELECT ServicePrice, ServiceDuration FROM SalonService WHERE PlaceID = ? AND ServiceID IN (${tokens});`; // The query
```

Now, you can be sure if there is no serviceId or 1 you can populate your query well.

Comment: Its working well with 2 services but if I got 3+ services I got that bug inside the query:  "SELECT ServicePrice, ServiceDuration FROM SalonService WHERE PlaceID = 'x' AND ServiceID IN ('2', '1', '3',?);" and the ? should not be here and so on if we add more services

Comment: It seems the expectation here is not clear. If you can elaborate it more, may be I can write better answer.

Comment: I need to retrieve price for each service with one single query. My problem is that the query seems to be ok, even the token. I generate a "?" for each service and I add it inside the query. The problem is that when the query is executed its not working well because its adding always a "?" that should not be here. I tried only with service, deleting the placeID = ? and its working, but if we add two conditions its not working well

Comment: Any help or solution?

Comment: I think you can use an empty string instead of using `?`.

Comment: I can't use an empty string because I need to generate dynamic ? for the query